Do I have a chance? Should I even try?
I hold a BA in Software Engineering from a mid-level university (GPA: 3.9/5) and a course-based M.S. in Artificial Intelligence from a top 5 university in my country (GPA: 3.95/5). Although I lack research experience and have no published papers, I have three years of professional experience in software engineering, specializing in front-end development, React, JavaScript, Django, FastAPI, Docker, logging, networking, and related areas.
I am 26 years old, live in Iran, and anticipate an IELTS score of 7-7.5 based on mock tests. I also face financial constraints and will require a scholarship for further studies.
Considering my background, what are my chances of gaining admission to an English-taught, research-based M.S. program in Artificial Intelligence in Austria, Denmark, Spain, Ireland, Italy, or the UK?
Additionally, I have almost three years remaining before I can begin applying, as I need to complete my compulsory military service. I have applied for a program that will allow me to work professionally during this time, which would bring my total work experience to five or six years.
Will it be too late to apply when I am 28/29 years old?

None of these countries will provide you with funding. There's basically no funding for masters students even for home students,  never mind those coming from abroad. This might be a bigger problem than age/admissions

I suggest that you ignore the age issue and just apply. That is the only way to know if you "have a chance". Make sure that you know the requirements for admission and the expectations of the admissions system anywhere you apply. For example, how high is the weight given to each element such as GPA, prior research, letters of recommendation, etc. Most of them are out of your control (the past is the past), but not all. And, your background might match requirements of some programs better than others. Focus your efforts as much as you can on where you might have the best chance.
During your wait before applying, make sure you keep in contact with possible recommenders so that you aren't forgotten.

This is from a UK perspective:
Your chance to be admitted into a research master are decent. There is no general expectation that you would have any research experience whatsoever - a research master in the UK is for getting your initial exposure to research. It would be better if your grades were higher, but professional experience can indeed compensate for that. It will be a significant factor whether there is a suitable and interested supervisor available.
However, funding is going to be a huge issue. Funding for Master degrees is very rare in the UK, and quite a bit of the little available funding is reserved for British citizens/residents.
Overall, I think your chances to find a funded PhD position in the UK are better than your chances to find a funded Masters. The former are still not great - also on the PhD level a lot of funding is restricted to locals, and there is a lot of competition for the internationally available funding.

Since you are interested in research and have  coursework MS anyway, why not apply for a PhD? A PhD is much more likely to come with funding than an MS.
Since you have a few years, work on improving your English in the meantime, as 7.0 is typically around the minimum score required and you will find things easier if your English is stronger.
Whether your GPAs are considered excellent or mediocre depends strongly on what country you completed your studies in, as grading systems vary widely. 80% is outstanding in France or the UK, for example, but pretty average in the US due to different assessment practices. Each university you apply to will make its own assessment of this, but you can get a pretty good idea from online world grade conversion websites.
What your referees say about your research potential also matters. If there will be a delay or a few years, it is a good idea to ask a few potential academic referees to write letters now while you are fresh in their minds. They might need to rewrite them closer to the time, but they’ll have strong drafts to update rather than having to try to remember who you are.

I can’t vouch for the numbers, but this seems like decent practical guidance. No idea what the down-voter was concerned about.
